# How to make Jenkins trigger a build when RSS is updated?

Tags: build, rss, jenkins, rtc

I have a SCM that only allows HTTP push/pull/poll requests. Without modifying my SCM, I would like Jenkins to trigger a build (as soon as possible) when new code is checked in.

Developers usually get notified of new code via a RSS Feed.

Is there a recommended Jenkins plugin that can help with this?

Comment: [This plugin might work for you](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/URLTrigger+Plugin).

Comment: I've [filed an issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20915) with the URLTrigger plugin to simplify triggering by Atom / RSS feeds. Please consider upvoting that issue if you are interested.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Git then there is github plugin. Git will notify Jenkins whenever there is a new commit.

If you are using svn, use the feature poll scm. Specify a time interval so that Jenkins will look for new commits based on configured time.